# Three.js set object opacity/transparent

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I am creating a scene with some parts which are loaded from a JSON file.
I can hide and show every single object. But now I want to set the opacity/transparent for a single object.

I creating the objects with this code.

```
    geometryArray = new Object();
    var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
    for(var i = 0; i < jsonFileNames.length; i++){
        var layerName = jsonFileNames[i].split("/")[1].slice(0, -5);
        loader.load(layerName, jsonFileNames[i], function(geometry, materials, layerName){
            mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors, side:THREE.DoubleSide, transparent: true}));
            mesh.scale.set(scaleFactor, scaleFactor, scaleFactor);
            mesh.name = layerName;
            scene.add(mesh);
            geometryArray[layerName] = mesh;
        }, layerName);
    }
```

And I can show/hide the objects with this code

```
geometryArray[layerName].visible = true;
```

But how can I set the opacity/transparent for an object?

I have tried to work with this code but this doesnt work.

```
geometryArray[layerName].materials[0].opacity
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to also set

```
geometryArray[layerName].materials[0].transparent = true
```

on the material for it to use the opacity.

Comment: I have tested this but I get the error that the property "0" is undefined. I think that should be a problem with the materials.

Comment: It should probably be ```geometryArray[layerName].material.transparent = true```.

Comment: Also, for clarity, I would suggest renaming `geometryArray` to `objects`.

Answer (score -1):

`material.transparent` only accepts Boolean value not number value

```
WRONG !!!!! material.transparent = 0 or material.transparent = 1

RIGHT ------> material.transparent = true or material.transparent = false
```